# How to use R to read Excel, create tables, get formatted tables back into GIS with coordinate locations

Tags: r, excel, maps, gis

I'm new to R - which will be obvious in a sec here...and I was hoping someone could point me to the some packages to attempt to solve a specific problem:

I get Excel tables from scientists with analytical data for specific GIS point sample locations, we usually copy/paste these tables into the layout of GIS map documents; however quite often the line weights, fonts, etc get messed up...and the data gets updated/revised etc. - tedious copy/paste again...

I'd like to try to read these Excel files, have R create a multiple formatted tables for each sample location, and plot these tables with real world coordinates for use in GIS (ESRI or QGIS, etc.), where the tables would ideally show up offset some distance from the point sample locations in some sort of GIS file format.

I was thinking the export from R might be a .dwg, or even a raster geotiff with a transparent background...a format that would preserve formatting and position - not sure what the possibilities here could be...has anyone ever tried anything like this - I see several excel and geospatial packages, and understand that they can be used for regular geospatial data analysis, but in this case I'm trying to merge graphics (formatted tables from R) and GIS - which is something I'm having a hard time finding any info about.

Hopefully this question is not too vague...

edit - I have the SP package and am reading up on it, I guess I'm really stuck on the whole make several tables with R > get those tables all at once into a format that GIS can read - try this - imagine a georeferenced aerial photo - then imagine a layer of floating boxes on top of the aerial image, these boxes are placed with coordinates (i.e. lat/long, state plane feet, etc.) - can I make a layer like this with R and the geospatial packages?

Comment: There may be some help at the GIS stack exchange site. Also, not sure if this is a good enough source, but ESRI has an ArcGIS api for R that may be useful.

Comment: There's a whole task view for spatial (and temporal) data. http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Spatial.html You're after package `sp` and kin.

Comment: You can use raster images to add the tables to the maps, however, you would need to consider what behaviour you expect to happen when someone zooms in and out of the map. A raster is an image set to a specific size relative to the underlying map and will not behave nicely under when zooming. I remember using KML with Google Earth several years ago to have a formatted table appear when a marker was clicked, I haven't tried anything like this with QGIS, but would think that some of the labelling functionality may be helpful towards this.